# Storing and working with multi-output Tasks in mlr3

Tags: regression, mlr3, multitargeting

I have a **multitarget regression problem** and would like to include such a task/ learner in my mlr3 pipeline.

The only information I could find on this topic in the mlr3 information was this on GitHub: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3multioutput

Is there anything planned regarding the implementation of multitarget problems in mlr3 in the near future?
Unfortunately, I am quite new to mlr3 and haven't the necessary programming skills to implement anything for this on my own.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: currently the development is stalled and will presumable only be continued when there is someone who is 1. interested and 2. has time. So in case you need it anytime soon mlr3 is not the way to go, I am sorry.

Comment: okay, that was also my feeling - thanks a lot for your quick response!